# How to get value from a function call in JavaScript to display in PHP page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Recently I came across to this multiple selection vanilla JavaScript library - Select7. I implemented and modified some of the codes provided in GitHub by the creator. It gives three lines of codes to show the three different results show. I wonder where should I put them if I want to display the values in my PHP codes. These are the codes:

```
<div id="your_id" class="select7_container">
<div class="select7_arrow">&#9662;</div>
<div class="select7_placeholder">Meme Review</div>
<select class="select7_select" onchange="Select7.add(this, event);">
    <option class="select7_hide" value="filler"></option>
    <option value="option1">Hello World</option>
    <option value="option2">Yes Mate</option>
    <option value="option3">Ma Dude</option>
</select>
<div class="select7_items"></div>
</div>

//You can get the texts and the values
Select7.get('your_id');

//You can get only the values
Select7.get('your_id','value');

//You can get only the texts
Select7.get('your_id','text');
```

Comment: Why not just use a form and set whatever values or text I side the fields, maybe set some extra hidden fields and just post the form to the PHP file where PHP can simply use _GET or _POST? You can also add them to an url and call the url with window.location.href('// url comes here'); and then you can again access the url parameters with _GET.

Comment: But best would be to use Ajax so that the page needs no reloading. So call a REST API or whatever API using JS on the front to call the PHP functions on the server and pass them like that. That is best practice although if you want it fast and dirty you could also simply use cookies, set them on client using js document.cookie and access them with PHP using _COOKIE

Comment: I heard about AJAX but I want to try using the Select7 above to display chose options on PHP page.

Comment: Javascript runs in browser and php runs on server. Neither knows anything about the other. What you are asking is far too broad.

Comment: Yeah but believe me I can simply use cookies or forms or url to pass js data from front so that PHP can access. A lot of same questions and answers and it does work but best is to call the server using an Ajax call using JS in the front and call an API so that no page refresh is needed. https://www.coderslexicon.com/the-basics-of-passing-values-from-javascript-to-php-and-back/ or simply Google it... https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+pass+data+from+javascript+to+php. And believe me or not but I have from day 1 experience with PHP and JS as Senior and wrote major web applications using PHP

Comment: Select7 is a simple front end script written in js but it is no more than a form. So no way using Select7 to pass the values to PHP or even better not any server side language. You will need Ajax which calls an API or an url or use js post for example as jQuery does. They have jQuery.post, jQuery.cookie and jQuery.Ajax so you can take a look at that although this is just a simple form but because it is actually not supported to multi select options like that you will first need to parse delected items using the Select7.get, assign result as value to an hidden field with stringify, Post form

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the advise. Looks like I need to learn Ajax and jQuery now. Is there any advise to learn both of the languages?

Comment: Okay..I will use cookies instead then.